# Is it possible to update a makefile variable from within a target section?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have my simple Makefile, it's something like this

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++17 ...
...
all : $(TARGETS)

% : src/%.cpp $(SRCFILES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(MACROS) $(INCLUDES) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

I want to add a `profile` targets that when called adds the `-pg` option to the `CXXFLAGS` variable and then calls the all targets.

I tried

```
profile:
    CXXFLAGS += -pg
    all
```

but this doesn't work and gives the error:

> $ make profile 
> CXXFLAGS += -pg 
> make: CXXFLAGS: Command not found

Comment: Following a target like your `profile:` line, the next line with a leading TAB and CXXFLAGS would be read as part of a recipe. Try a separate line: `some-target: CXXFLAGS += -pg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered that syntax cannot work.  Recipes are not makefile commands, they are shell scripts and are run in a shell.

You should use [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) for this:

```
profile: CXXFLAGS += -pg
profile: all
```

I should point out that while this seems useful, it's not always as handy as it could be.  If you want to build the same targets (e.g., `.o` files) with different flags you will have to be careful to always run `clean` by hand between builds else you'll get a mishmash of objects built different ways.

Generally after some time with this people decide what they really want to do is build the different types of targets into different directories so they don't get mixed up.  Once you do that you need different rules and then you might as well just put the extra flags there.  But, target-specific variables are still handy in some situations.